# How to change Android Studio default Welcome Screen/Splash Screen?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to ask about how to change the **welcome screen / splash screen** on default **Android Studio IDE**.

Could it be possible if I disable the welcome screen image ?

Thanks for helping me. :)

Comment: Instead of that , what do you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by pressing ctrl, +, ESC all the 3 keys together.

Comment: i've tried that but it only open the windows search

Comment: I am currently using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure about removing it, but if you want to change it use a program like [Resource Tuner](http://www.heaventools.com/download.htm) or other programs to Reverse Engineer EXE and substitute  the splash screen image.

This is before and after in Resource Tuner

[image]
[image]